# Why does `echo $(find) | wc -l` not count the number of files correctly?

Tags: bash

Thats my function

```
function getFile(){
    echo $(find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex ${REGEX:-'.*\.(jpe?g|JPE?g)$'})
}
```

when i try to get that getFile return in my other funtion

```
function resize(){
    (( i=1 ))
    local k=`getFile | wc -l`
    echo $k
}
```

i don't have the same result if I do

```
function resize(){
    (( i=1 ))
    local k=`find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex ${REGEX:-'.*\.(jpe?g|JPE?g)$'} | wc -l`
    echo $k
}
```

Comment: `echo $(seq 3) | wc -l` and `echo "$(seq 3)" | wc -l` print different numbers. Does that give you a hint?

Comment: `echo $(cmd)` is a "useless" echo. The cmd's output is already being sent to stdout. The getFile function should just have the find command in it.

Comment: What is the point of `echo $(cmd)`? Just do `cmd`.  The only difference between the two is manipulating whitespace, which is almost always unwanted.  If you really want to manipulate whitespace like that, it deserves to be handled explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting lines of output from `find` is fragile, in that *conceivably* a filename could contain a newline. Since you don't appear to be constrained by POSIX compatibility, I would use something like

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex "${REGEX:-.*\.(jpe?g|JPE?g)$}" -printf '.' | wc -c
```

to get the count. (No matter what the file's name is, `find` simply outputs a single *character* for `wc` to count.)

If you still need `getFile` to produce actual file names on occasion (with the caveat that a single output line may not be a complete file name), you can parameterize the function, for example:

```
getFile () {
  find_opts=(. -type f -regextype egrep -regex ${REGEX:-'.*\.(jpe?g|JPE?g)$'})
  count=
  for arg; do
    case $arg in
      -c) find_opts+=(-printf '.'); count=1 ;;
    esac
  done

  find "${find_opts[@]}" | if [ -z "$count" ]; then cat; else wc -c; fi
}
```

Then you can run

```
$ getfile
foo.jpg
bar.jpg
```

or

```
$ getfile -c
2
```

Comment: find whatever -printf . | wc -l will always print 0, better switch to wc -c

Comment: For some reason, I was thinking that `-printf` added a newline automatically, unlike the `printf` command. Then I forgot to check that assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the `getFile` function. What you do there is to find the names of the jpeg (or whatever) files and then `echo` those. What it does is to print all of those in a single line. For instance, here's what I've got

```
./photo_2019-07-18_22-20-451.jpg ./photo_2019-07-18_22-20-45.jpg
```

Then you try to count those with `wc -l` which basically counts the number of lines in the output, thus it always gets 1.

On the other hand in the 2nd function, you don't echo the results that it is not a single line anymore, giving the right answer.

Simply remove the `echo` from `getFile()` and it will work

```sh
function getFile() {
    find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex ${REGEX:-'.*\.(jpe?g|JPE?g)$'};
}
```

it outputs

```
$ getFile

./photo_2019-07-18_22-20-451.jpg
./photo_2019-07-18_22-20-45.jpg
```

and finally

```
function resize(){
    (( i=1 ))
    local k=`getFile | wc -l`
    echo $k
}
```

```
$ resize
2
```